# How to calculate the duration that a value stayed constant in R?

Tags: r

I've a matrix as follows:

```
        TIME  YORN
 [1,]   24  0
 [2,]   26  0
 [3,]   28  0
 [4,]   30  1
 [5,]   32  0
 [6,]   34  1
 [7,]   36  0
 [8,]   38  0
 [9,]   40  0
[10,]   42  0
[11,]   44  1
[12,]   45  0
[13,]   48  1
[14,]   50  1
[15,]   53  1
[16,]   54  1
[17,]   56  1
[18,]   58  0
[19,]   60  1
[20,]   62  0
[21,]   64  1
[22,]   67  1
[23,]   68  1
[24,]   70  1
[25,]   72  1
[26,]   74  1
[27,]   89  1
```

I want to calculate the total duration of 'TIME' for which the 'YORN' value stayed as 1 continuously more than once (instead of becoming 0 immediately).

How to achieve this in R?

Comment: What do exactly mean by total duration of time? Do you want last value of time minus the first one in each chunk?

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Not last value minus the first one but the difference between each two time values in the chunk and then the sum of all those differences.. Why separate differences is because the time values in the chunks are not in sequence. So, sum of all those differences is what I finally want to calculate.

Comment: You probably should provide some feedback on the answers provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible `rle` solution (I couldn't figure how to simplify this), assuming `dat` is your matrix

```
temp <- rle(dat[, 2] == 1L) # capture sequences of 1
temp$values[temp$lengths == 1L] <- FALSE # set all the smaller than 2 sequences to FALSE
indx <- inverse.rle(temp) # reverse back to the original vector size but with correct indexes
indx2 <- cumsum(c(1L, diff(which(indx == 1L))) > 1L) # separate to groups
sum(tapply(dat[indx, 1], indx2, function(x) diff(range(x)))) # sum the differences
## [1] 33
```

Answer (score 0):

If the correct result is 33:

```
m <- structure(c(24L, 26L, 28L, 30L, 32L, 34L, 36L, 38L, 40L, 42L, 
44L, 45L, 48L, 50L, 53L, 54L, 56L, 58L, 60L, 62L, 64L, 67L, 68L, 
70L, 72L, 74L, 89L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Dim = c(27L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("TIME", "YORN"
)))

start <- c(m[1,2] == 1L, diff(m[,2]) == 1L)
end <- c(diff(m[,2]) == -1L, m[nrow(m),2] == 1L)

sum(m[end, 1] - m[start, 1])
#[1] 33
```

Otherwise, you need to adjust this.

Answer (score 0):

A dplyr solution:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(
    changed = !is.na(lag(YORN)) & YORN != lag(YORN)) %>%
  group_by(cumsum(changed), YORN) %>%
  filter(min(TIME) != max(TIME) & YORN == 1) %>%
  summarize(TOTAL = sum(TIME - lag(TIME), na.rm = TRUE )) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  summarize(TOTAL = sum(TOTAL))
```